# String cut by a separator with the separator in the respective list element in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.6.5

Is there any better solution than this one? Particularly the last line. I don't like it.

```
import re
s = "my_separator first thing my_separator second thing"
data = re.split("(my_separator )", s)[1:]
data = [even+odd for i, odd in enumerate(data) for j, even in enumerate(data) if i%2==1 and j%2==0 and i==j+1]
```

Comment: No need for regex at all. [`str.split`](https://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/stdtypes#str.split) can accept string separator.

Comment: @hjpotter92 it can however I don't know how to call it to keep the separator. It removes it from the results however if you enclose `re.split` expression in a group (`()`) it keeps the separators in the results (but puts them separately from the results).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can exploit `zip` and `iter`ators to allow you to pair things together:

```
data = [a + b for a, b in zip(*[iter(data)]*2)]
```

---

You could use just `re`, and change the separator with a look ahead assertion.

```
data = re.split(" (?=my_separator)", s)
```

---

You can use `str.split`, and just add the separator back:

```
sep = 'my_separator '
data = s.split(sep)[1:]
data = [sep + i for i in data]
```

```
data = [sep + i for i in s.split(sep)]
```

Comment: Didn't know about `itertools` recipes, thanks a lot! I consider the lookahead most elegant as I won't have to process it then.

Comment: The lookahead is not as general as I thought because split has to consume something and that something has to precede the separator :-( `pairwise` it is!

Comment: `pairwise` cuts it as `(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),...`, my code does `(1,2),(3,4),...`.

Comment: @VaNa My bad, yes, I've fixed that

Comment: @VaNa: The lookahead works fine, just not in Python. :-/ In Ruby : `"my_separator first thing my_separator second thing".split(/(?=my_separator)/)`. Done!

Answer (score 6):

As [already commented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194444/string-cut-by-a-separator-with-the-separator-in-the-respective-list-element-in-p?noredirect=1#comment374079_194444), use the [`str.split()`](https://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/stdtypes#str.split) version itself:

```
SEPARATOR = "my_separator "
s = "my_separator first thing my_separator second thing"
data = [SEPARATOR + part for part in s.split(SEPARATOR) if part]
```

Comment: You meant it like this! You won! :-D

Comment: Note that it doesn't work if `'my_separator'` isn't present in the string.

Answer (score 2):

[hjpotters92’s answer](/a/194466/93659) is great for fixed separator strings. If the separators vary and one wants to join them with each subsequent match one can use the following two approaches, neither of which requires closures:

### 1 Generator function

```
def split_with_separator1(s, sep):
    tokens = iter(re.split(sep, s))
    next(tokens)
    while True:
        yield next(tokens) + next(tokens)
```

The expression inside the loop works because the Python language guarantees left-to-right evaluation (unlike many other languages, e. g. C).

### 2 Interleaved slices and binary map

```
import operator

def split_with_separator2(s, sep)
    tokens = re.split(sep, s)
    return map(operator.add, tokens[1::2], tokens[2::2])
```

Of course one can slice with `itertools.islice` instead if one doesn't want to create two ephemeral token list copies.

Answer (score 1):

your last line "repaired"

```
import re
s = "my_separator first thing my_separator second thing"
data = re.split("(my_separator )", s)[1:]
data = [data[i]+data[i+1] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]
```

Comment: Although this one does not seem to be that elegant, it is correct and better than mine. Thanks!